# Is there a way to custom WAL filename and other temp files in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, node-sqlite3

I am using `@journeyapps/sqlcipher` package, a fork of `node-sqlite3`.
And I am looking for a way to customize the filename of the temp files generated by SQLite.

Example :

- `mydb-wal` => `mywal`
- `mydb-wal` => `mydb15`
- `mydb-shm` => `myshmfoo`

> Any suggestion is appreciated 
> Thanks in advance.

Comment: Short of editing the sqlite source code, I don't think so.

Comment: Hi @Shawn, if SQLite have only one function responsable of returning the filename.

Comment: I have already edited h2 database source to achieve this.
The h2 has a global variables containing the prefix and suffixes of the temp files.
Is SQLite have those global variables or function that can edit easily ?

Comment: Yup, the names are hard-coded values you can only change by editing the source and using a custom sqlite3 library. -wal in pager.c and -shm in os_unix.c and os_win.c. Oh, and you forgot mydb-journal.

Comment: Thak you @Shawn.